# Create a sequence of pairs equally spaced

Tags: r, sequence

I want to create a vector composed by N pairs of real where each pairs are separated by a value S and the two elements of the pair are separate by a a value iS, that could be written like that:

```
V=[(X,X+iS)_1, (X+S+iS,X+S+2*iS)_2, ...  ]
```

So if we start from `X=1`, with `S=1` and `iS = .5` it should return:

```
V=[1.0,1.5,2.5,3.0,4.0,4.5]
```

I create this function that does exactly what i want:

```
myseq<-function(x,n,sep,isep){
  res=c(x,x+isep)
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
      prev=res[length(res)]
      res=c(res,c(prev+sep,prev+sep+isep))
  }
  return(res)
}
```

With the same example than before:

```
> myseq(1,3,1,.5)                                                             
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.5
```

But I am sure it could be written in a simpler and more "functional" way, but I can't figure it out. 
If you have any Idea?

Comment: Please show some reproducible example and expected output

Comment: thanks @Henrik you are right, I will correct that.

Comment: Unless, I'm missing something, `cumsum(c(x, rep_len(c(isep, sep), (n * 2) - 1)))` seems valid for what you describe, too.

Comment: indeed it works, I will answer with benchamrks of the differents solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my question I realized that my accepted answer was maybe not the best one and that @alexis_laz in his comment came up with a short and better solution.
I put them here again, and after benchmarking it seems that

My original version:

```
original<-function(x,n,sep,isep){
    res=c(x,x+isep)
    for(i in 1:(n-1)){
        prev=res[length(res)]
        res=c(res,c(prev+sep,prev+sep+isep))
    }
    return(res)
}
```

The previously accepted answer:

```
accepted <- function(x,isep,sep,n){
    c(rbind(seq(x,by = isep+sep, length.out = n), seq(x+isep,by = isep+sep, length.out = n))) 
}
```

Alexis' comment:

```
alexcomm <- function(x,n,sep,isep){
    cumsum(c(x, rep_len(c(isep, sep), (n * 2) - 1)))
}
```

And the benchmark:

```
                      expr        min          lq        mean      median
 alexcomm(x, n, sep, isep)     99.657    105.0090    149.4527    109.1745
  accepted(x, isep, sep, n)    130.090    137.7555    193.6189    163.2150
  original(x, n, sep, isep) 251176.761 258936.2820 268247.7626 270124.8435
```

Thus the solution proposed in comment is not only the short but also slightly quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one idea using `seq`,

```
myseq <- function(x, n, sep, isep) {
  v1 <- seq(x, n*2, sep)[c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, (isep/sep)-1))]
  return(v1[1:(n*2)])
  }

myseq(1,3, 0.5, 1)  
#[1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.5
```

Comment: this one isn't working for all the case (`myseq(1,3,1,.1)` for exemple)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more approach where you create 2 different vectors and then combine them alternatively in order to get the desired sequence.

```
myfun=function(i,x,y,n){
    c(rbind(seq(i,by = x+y, length.out = n), seq(i+x,by = x+y, length.out = n)))
}

myfun(1,0.5,1,3)
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 3.0 4.0 4.5
```